# How click button in CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

I can't figure out how to click this button with CasperJS.
So far, I've been using `thenClick` and searching for the link with `a[href='']` but I can't do that for this button. It shows this when I inspect the element of the button:

```
<a style="float"href="javascript:void(0)"onclick="$('#divNewSection').slideToggle()">add...</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to click that link. You have to find a unique way to address it.

For example:

1. `casper.click("a[style='float']")`
2. `casper.click("a[style='float'][onclick*='.slideToggle()']")`
3. `casper.click('a[onclick="$(\'#divNewSection\').slideToggle()"]')`
4. `casper.click(x("//a[text()='add...']"))` where `var x = require('casper').selectXPath;`